# C++: Derived + Base class implement a single interface?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface

In C++, is it possible to have a base plus derived class implement a single interface?

For example:

```
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction() = 0;
        virtual void DerivedFunction() = 0;
};

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction(){}
};

class Derived : public Base, public Interface
{
    public: 
        void DerivedFunction(){}
};

void main()
{
    Derived derived;
}
```

This fails because Derived can not be instantiated. As far as the compiler is concerned Interface::BaseFunction is never defined.

So far the only solution I've found would be to declare a pass through function in Derived

```
class Derived : public Base, public Interface
{
    public: 
        void DerivedFunction(){}
        void BaseFunction(){ Base::BaseFunction(); }
};
```

Is there any better solution?

---

**EDIT:** If it matters, here is a real world problem I had using MFC dialogs.

I have a dialog class (MyDialog lets say) that derives from CDialog. Due to dependency issues, I need to create an abstract interface (MyDialogInterface). The class that uses MyDialogInterface needs to use the methods specific to MyDialog, but also needs to call CDialog::SetParent. I just solved it by creating MyDialog::SetParent and having it pass through to CDialog::SetParent, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++ doesn't notice the function inherited from Base already implements `BaseFunction`: The function has to be implemented explicitly in a class derived from `Interface`. Change it this way:

```
class Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction() = 0;
        virtual void DerivedFunction() = 0;
};

class Base : public Interface
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction(){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public: 
        virtual void DerivedFunction(){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
}
```

If you want to be able to get away with only implementing one of them, split `Interface` up into two interfaces:

```
class DerivedInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void DerivedFunction() = 0;
};

class BaseInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction() = 0;
};

class Base : public BaseInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void BaseFunction(){}
};

class Derived : public DerivedInterface
{
    public: 
        virtual void DerivedFunction(){}
};  

class Both : public DerivedInterface, public Base {
    public: 
        virtual void DerivedFunction(){}
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    Base base;
    Both both;
}
```

Note: main must return int
Note: it's good practise to keep `virtual` in front of member functions in the derived that were virtual in the base, even if it's not strictly required.

Comment: If you do it that way, then you don't need the second declaration of BaseFunction.

Comment: It's what he wrote. I didnt want to change it. He might have reason to di it like that

Comment: No problem, I just didn't want him or others to go through eternity thinking it was needed. :)

Comment: 2 problems: 
- Now BAse cannt be instantiated on it's own.
- Other classes that derive from base now have to implement DerivedFunction
    class OtherDerived : public Base
    {
        public: 
            void OtherDerivedFunction(){}
    };

Comment: I edited the code. I didn't mean to put the second declaration of BaseFunction

Comment: Make two interfaces, one for BaseFunction and one for DerivedFunction.

Comment: In your original example, you couldn't instantiate Base anyway.  The second problem is also an issue with your original example.

Comment: Yes, Joe. You need to do two interfaces then. It doesn't work this way like in Java.

Comment: i added the two-interfaces solution

Comment: I like your answers, but I think the pass-through function is actually easiest. Your Both class defines its own implementation, while I'd want a way to use the implementations in Base and Derived. I realize that I very well could be designing my classes like a fool. :)

Comment: For the second bit, I think you meant "class Derived : public Base, public DerivedInterface"

Comment: I didn't mean it. but if you wanted that behaivor, i can indeed change it

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: "it's good practise to keep virtual": Tis should be updated now we have C++11 defining `override`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's not quite the case that Derived "is-a" Base, which suggests that containment may be a better implementation than inheritance.

Also, your Derived member functions should be decalred as virtual as well.

```
class Contained
{
    public:
        void containedFunction() {}
};

class Derived
{
    public:
        virtual void derivedFunction() {}
        virtual void containedFunction() {return contained.containedFunction();}
    private:
        Containted contained;
};
```

You can make the contained member a reference or smart pointer if you want to hide the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with your example, you have two implementations of `Interface`, the one coming from `Base` and the one coming from `Derived`.  This is by design in the C++ language.  As already pointed out, just remove the `Interface` base class on the definition of `Derived`.

Comment: um.. no.... Check the code again.  Base does not inherit from Interface. (Interface has DerviceFunction which is not implemented in Base)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer by litb. However, there's an opportunity here to understand something of how virtual functions and multiple inheritance work.

When a class has multiple base classes, it has separate vtables for each base class. `Derived` will have a vtable structure that looks like this:

```
Derived
 vtable: Interface
   BaseFunction*
   DerivedFunction*
 vtable: Base
   BaseFunction*
```

Additionally, each base class will only be able to see its own vtable. When `Base` is instantiated, it fills in the `Base::BaseFunction` pointer in the vtable, but can't see the vtable for Interface.

If the code you provided could compile, the resulting vtable structure of an instance of `Derived` would look like this:

```
Derived
 vtable: Interface
   BaseFunction* = 0
   DerivedFunction* = Derived::DerivedFunction
 vtable: Base
   BaseFunction* = Base::BaseFunction
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one thing lacking from litb's answer. If I have a `Derived` instance, I can get a `DerivedInterface` and `BaseInterface`. But if I only have a `DerivedInterface` I can't get a `BaseInterface` since deriving `DerivedInterface` from `BaseInterface` won't work.

But, this whole time I've been limiting myself to compile time checking for some reason.  This `DerivedInterface` works just great:

```
class DerivedInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void DerivedFunction() = 0;
        BaseInterface* GetBaseInterface()
            {return dynamic_cast<BaseInterface*>(this);}
};

void main()
{
    Derived derived;

    DerivedInterface* derivedInterface = &derived;
    derivedInterface->GetBaseInterface()->BaseFunction();
}
```

No pass through functions necessary in Derived, and everyone is happy. Sure, it's not strictly an interface anymore, but that's fine. Why didn't I think of that sooner? :)

Comment: that's no problem. you just make a class derive from DerivedInterface and BaseInterface, and then you have exactly the interface of your "Interface" class in your original question

Comment: anyway. never use dynamic_cast like that :) dynamic_cast should be a last resort to work around what one cannot do by designing correct interfaces. in your case, just do Interface as i told in the comment above, and then you can do BaseInterface* baseInterface = &derived; and call both :)

Comment: Yes, that will give me the same interface, but a different implementation, which is the whole point. I have the implementation for a base and derived class, and I need a single interface for them. It sounds like this is as close as I'll get.

Comment: wait, I was referring to you "both" class about which defines its own implementation. Hmmmm.